# Deploying React - django apps on Azure web apps

Tags: python, reactjs, django, azure

Locally, I am able to run my django app and react app.
I migrated the django app to the azure web apps.
My question is, what is best practice regarding connecting the react app to the django app. Should I start another web app instance, or should I try to run both on the same instance?

Comment: Highly dependent on the use case and the rest of your stack/environment. In some cases, the entire stack in one place makes sense. In general though, separating API from frontend makes scalability much more attainable. The Django application might require more computational power, while the React app might even be served from a a lightweight server or a CDN. It's hard to say with this little information though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is that both React and Django are deployed on the same instance, however it depends on your need.

There are many ways to deploy Django + React, I will mentioned only two:

1. Simple one: Just import react libraries into your Django template and deploy your Django on the instance as a normal Django project.  You may refer to this tutorial on how to accomplish this: [Add React to Django Template](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-add-react-js-into-django-24e79e67e992)
2. Second way which I would recommend: Deploy Django and React separately. Django app to be deployed on the Azure instance and react to be deployed as a static website on Azure Blob storage (You may refer to this tutorial: [Host React on Azure Blob](https://antbutcher.medium.com/hosting-a-react-js-app-on-azure-blob-storage-azure-cdn-for-ssl-and-routing-8fdf4a48feeb)). In this case, your react app will be using the Django exposed APIs (through Django DRF). You may refer to this tutorial for further details: [Deploy React + Django](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-to-do-application-using-django-and-react)